# Selenium: WebElement.click() is opening a new tab in Chrome, but new window in IE & FF

Tags: java, internet-explorer, firefox, selenium, automated-tests

I'm attempting to automate a test case which asks to validate that clicking on a few links results in them opening in a New Tab, or New Window.

When I manually click on these links, it opens the links in a New Tab in all of the below browsers. But when I use `WebElement.click()`, the following occurs in each browsers:

- Chrome: Opens link in New Tab (as expected)
- Firefox and IE: Opens link in New Window (as opposed to New Tab, when manually clicking)

**Question is:** Why the inconsistency opposed to manual click? I've read that this `.click()` method is the most similar to an actual user's click. But I'm not getting the same result as when I manually click.

> Chrome version: "Version 40.0.2214.91 m"
>
> Firefox version: "40.0.3"
>
> Internet Explorer version: "11.0.9600.17801"
>   Scripting language: Java
>
> Selenium: selenium-java-2.45.0

Comment: IE Settings: "When a new tab is opened, open: 'The new tab page'
When a pop-up is encountered: 'Always open pop-ups in a new tab'
Open links from other programs in: 'A new tab in the current window'

FF Settings: 'Open new windows in a new tab instead' (Checked)

Comment: go for Ctrl+Click using Actions()